# look up data starting from one week from input date and display as columns

Tags: sql, oracle

For a report I'm making, I have this query here:

```
select
gam.bank_id,
gam.sol_id,
gam.acct_crncy_code Account_Currency,
gam.gl_sub_head_code GLSH_Code,
gam.foracid,
(select tran_date_bal from tbaadm.eab
    where eab.eod_date = (select max(eab.eod_date) from tbaadm.eab
        where gam.acid = eab.acid
            and eab.eod_date <= '3-Jun-2013')
    and gam.acid = eab.acid
    and gam.bank_id = eab.bank_id) balance_1,
```

which gets the end-of-day balance of an account depending on the input end-of-day-date. What I need to do next is to also display the EOD balance of the account for one whole week (in this case, since June 3, 2013 is my input date, i also need to display the EOD balances of the accounts from June 2, June 1... down to May 28). I also need to display them as columns in the result set. So far, what I have done is this:

```
(select tran_date_bal from tbaadm.eab
    where eab.eod_date = (select max(eab.eod_date) from tbaadm.eab
        where gam.acid = eab.acid
            and eab.eod_date <= to_date('3-Jun-2013') - 1)
    and gam.acid = eab.acid
    and gam.bank_id = eab.bank_id) balance_2,
(select tran_date_bal from tbaadm.eab
    where eab.eod_date = (select max(eab.eod_date) from tbaadm.eab
        where gam.acid = eab.acid
            and eab.eod_date <= to_date('3-Jun-2013') - 2)
    and gam.acid = eab.acid
    and gam.bank_id = eab.bank_id) balance_3
.
.
.
(select tran_date_bal from tbaadm.eab
    where eab.eod_date = (select max(eab.eod_date) from tbaadm.eab
        where gam.acid = eab.acid
            and eab.eod_date <= to_date('3-Jun-2013') - 6)
    and gam.acid = eab.acid
    and gam.bank_id = eab.bank_id) balance_7
```

As you can see, yup, I pretty much hard-coded the damn thing. Thing is, as I clarified the specs of the report more and more, I need to add more columns which would also look up on what days the dates were (June 3, 2013 is Monday, June 2 is Sunday... May 28 is Tuesday), and also the corresponding exchange rates for those dates. Of course, at this rate, hard-coding those things would only make the query too bloated, and in the future there might still be other data that I have to fetch starting from one whole week before the input date.

My question now, is if there's another, more efficient way to do this in Oracle, wherein the query looks up on data starting from one week up to the given date, and that the data would appear as columns on the query.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately no, we do the same thing in my company's reporting as well since your subquery uses gam.acid = eab.acid and gam.acid is needed in your subquery I am assuming "gam" is a driving table or one of your main tables in your query, then you have to run this iteration for each gam.acid

sometimes we code our report that way, and some times we use left join for each criteria instead of having the subquery in our select statement, depends on the dev's preference but both return the same thing, same performance.